# Web Api - The 'ObjectContent type failed to serialize

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Web API action.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get() {
  var units = Enum.GetValues(typeof(UnitType)).Cast<UnitType>().Select(x => new { Id = (Int32)x, Description = x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description });
  return Ok(units);
}
```

Basically, I am returning the values and descriptions of an enum.

I checked units list and I get the right values.

However, when I call the API I get the following error:

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage>  
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>Type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.</ExceptionMessage>
```

Why?

**UPDATE**

I now have:

```
  public IHttpActionResult Get() {
    IList<EnumModel> units = Enum.GetValues(typeof(UnitType)).Cast<UnitType>().Select(x => new EnumModel((Int32)x, x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)).ToList();
    return Ok(units);
  } // Get

public class EnumModel {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Description { get; set; }

  public EnumModel(Int32 id, String description) {
    Id = id;
    Description = description;
  } // EnumModel
} // EnumModel
```

I get the error:

```
<Error>
  <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
  <ExceptionMessage>The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage>  
  <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
  <StackTrace/><InnerException>
  <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
  <ExceptionMessage>Type 'Helpers.EnumModel' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.</ExceptionMessage>  
   <ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException</ExceptionType>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but the `InnerException` seems to be suggesting that anonymous types can't be serialized.

Try declaring a class such as

```
public class EnumInfo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public EnumInfo(int id, string description) {
        Id = id;
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

and turning your `Select` call into

```
[...].Select(x => new EnumInfo((Int32)x, x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description);
```

Comment: @MDMoura could you please edit your question to include the error you're getting *now*?

Comment: I just updated my question ... My class seems quite normal so I am not sure why I am getting this error now.

Comment: @MDMoura have you tried marking the class with `DataContractAttribute` as the exception message suggests?

Comment: I found the error ... I added a default contructor to the class and now it works.

Comment: True, as far as I recall you need a parameterless constructor to serialize to XML.

Comment: I did not add DataContractAttribute as I knew that this should work without it so I was trying to figure what the problem was. So it was the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

How are you calling your API? It looks like it is trying to use XML formatter for content negotiation. However, XML serializer does not support anonymous types. Check out [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_anon) for the details.

To fix this behaviour, you should either send `Accept: application/json` header (if you are using Fiddler or tool like this), or explicitly tell your Web API that you need JSON formatter only:

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    // Use camel case formatting.
    SerializerSettings =
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    }
};
config.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);
```

Comment: In fact I am calling the API on the browser to test it ... So it is normal to get a XML. I change the anonymous type to a List<EnumInfo> as s.. suggested but I keep having the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: Shouldn't the caller to decide which type wants and not forcing a type (JSON, XML, ...) on the action?

Comment: @MDMoura definitely, this is the main idea of content negotiation; however, in most cases only JSON format is required.

Comment: But I don't mind to use a class instead of an anonymous type ... Why am I still getting the error? Any idea why?